# Loading different usercontrols on selection of checkbox in mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am working on wpf mvvm pattern.
I have designed multiple UserControls for different checkboxes. On selection of a checkbox, the corresponding UserControl should get loaded in the right side.

[image: The Input portion should be loaded with the corresponding UserControl as shown here]

For a single checkbox, I have added the UserControl in MainView.xaml as this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <UserControl Name="CCS01" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="5" >
       <local:CCS01 HorizontalAlignment="Left"></local:CCS01>
    </UserControl>
</StackPanel>
```

I have stored the list of Checkboxes in a datagrid in a different UserControl like this

```
<DataGrid Width="150" Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGridCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="40"  Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                     
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="85" Binding="{Binding Path=UsecaseName}" Header="UsecaseName" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
         </DataGridTextColumn>    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The viewmodel class is like this:

```
[![private string _usecaseName;
        public string UsecaseName
        {
            get { return _usecaseName; }
            set
            {
                _usecaseName = value != null ? value.Trim() : null;
                OnPropertyChanged("UsecaseName");
            }
        }

        private string _description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                _description = value != null ? value.Trim() : null;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
        private bool _IsSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _IsSelected; }
            set
            {
                _IsSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        private bool _AllSelected;
        public bool AllSelected
        {
            get { return _AllSelected; }
            set
            {
                _AllSelected = value;
                foreach (var reportListItemModel in UsecaseListItems)
                {
                    reportListItemModel.IsSelected = this._AllSelected;

                }

                OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected");

            }
        }


        private ObservableCollection<UseCase> _usecaseListItems = new ObservableCollection<UseCase>();
        public ObservableCollection<UseCase> UsecaseListItems
        {
            get { return _usecaseListItems; }
            set {
                _usecaseListItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UsecaseListItems");
            }
        }][1]][1]
```

In short, I want to divide the page into two columns, on the left I have a list of UserControls and right I want to view the selected UserControl (only one can be selected) and how to bind the selected checkbox with the respective UserControl in ViewModel class.

For reference, I am adding the image of UI here:

Answer (score 0):

You try Something like this :

*.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGray" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}"
              Name="dataGridCustomers" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
              SelectionChanged="dataGridCustomers_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="auto"  Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Binding="{Binding UsecaseName}" Header="UsecaseName" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="HostGrid" Margin="5">

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

*.cs (code behind)

```
private void dataGridCustomers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var SelectedItem = dataGridCustomers.SelectedItem;
    string UserControlName = ((UseCase)SelectedItem).UsecaseName;
    Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (var item in ass.GetTypes())
    {
        if (item.Name == UserControlName)
        {
            UserControl uc = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(item,null);
            HostGrid.Children.Add(uc);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can remove the checkbox, it would be better. Because the CheckBox allows multi-selection

Comment: Actually, The HostGrid which you are trying to represent is in different UserControl in my case.

Comment: and? wht'a the problem? you can change de name of the Grid if you want

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class `MyControl` with 2 properties `string Name` (will be binded to your datagrid) and `UserControl Control` it will be your control.
2. Create a list of your controls.
3. In your ViewModel create a `MyControl SelectedControl` property, this will tell you what's the selected controls, and bind it to the datagrid
4. In your View add a `ContentControl` and bind it to: `SelectedControl.Control`